# Where are the snapfire rules?

Tags: savage-worlds

On the weapons table, I see references to snapfire (for instance, the Barrett .50 lists it). I could not find any explanation of what it means in terms of game mechanics.

**Can anyone point me to the page where this is explained?** I have SW Deluxe Explorer's Edition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is on Page 55 of the Deluxe rules.

> **Snapfire Penalty:** Certain weapons, such as
>   sniper rifles, are very inaccurate if fired “from the
>   hip” rather than using their excellent sights or
>   scopes. If the character moves in the action he
>   fires, he suffers a –2 penalty.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.Stackexchange.com Ken!  Great first answer.

Comment: Thanks! I never got before "Selected gear notes" and couldn't find it after the table either (which is the natural location of these notes to me).